# where to put custom install, e.g. rails g myapp:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've seen people use this to install apps:

```
rails g someapp:install
```

This is a custom generation correct?
Where is the code to :install usually put or have to be put?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would write a rake task, usually located in `lib/tasks/`; the filename would look like this: `someapp_install.rake`

And its contents like this:

```
namespace :someapp do 

  desc "This installs my awesome app"
  task :install => :environment do

    # Code that does install stuff goes here...

  end

end
```